# Vagrant Homestead 'storage' folder permission denied

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

Running Laravel on Homestead gives the following errors:

> The stream or file "/var/www/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log" could
>   not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Now I understand that the permission for **storage** is not correct but trying the following didn't work:

- Setting file permissions in the guest VM - didn't work
- Changing file permission on the host machine (windows in this case) - didn't work
- Lastly, Adding the following to the Vagrantfile changed the owner of the storage folder but still gives the same error:
  `config.vm.synced_folder "~/project/storage", "~/project/storage", 
  owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"`

I'm not sure what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your VM after changing permissions in VM and host?

Comment: Yes. Used ```vagrant reloads --provision```, suspension and then restarting, restarting through VirtualBox and even restarted my machine. None of it worked. But creating a fresh VM and Laravel projected worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I didn't have any permission issues when using Laravel with Homestead; it worked out of the box.

Anyway, SSH into your Vagrant machine, move towards the project's root and run the following commands.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: I've tried this before but even trying it again didn't work.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information to work with? What version of Homestead are you running? And why are you using the Vagrantfile to sync your folder instead of Homestead.yaml?

Comment: Running the latest Homestead and Vagrant (downloaded today). Homstead.yaml is being used and I tried whatever I could find on the internet in it but nothing seems to work. So then I tried to use vagrant file and the didn't sole the problem either.

Comment: Be more specific, what didn't work? Was it the same issue? Is the project brand new or is it an existing one? Anyway, try getting rid of everything you set yourself, synced folders in Vagrantfile and Homestead.yaml. Then create a brand new Laravel project, use Homestead.yaml to sync the folder and try again. Be sure to run `vagrant reload --provision` whenever you change a setting.