# Laravel keep chmod storage folder

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, vagrant, chmod

When i access view in my laravel application, why is it always showed this error **every 1 minute**:

`file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/Code/myproject/storage/framework/cache/data/db/59/db59a863cb50aaccca0c973c049bd67971a7e3ae): failed to open stream: Permission denied` ?

When i run `chmod -R 777 storage/`, that'll work, but then it keep changing permission every 1 minute.

Even though I do:

- `php artisan config:cache`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan view:clear`
- `php artisan clear-compiled`

in my local machine, didn't work for me.

I'm using:

- Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.3
- Vagrant 2.0.2 (ubuntu18.04)
- Laravel 5.5
- PHP 7.2

Please help. Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant Homestead 'storage' folder permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276694/vagrant-homestead-storage-folder-permission-denied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the owner of the whole project with `chown`. Set the new owner `www-data`.

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

Comment: I'm not sure there's any disadvantage, it does seem to serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following and it somehow works for me:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Change the following paramaters:

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

To:

```
user = vagrant
group = vagrant
```

Remember to restart PHP FPM

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```